# Status of pins in RS232

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication

I have set(), reset() routines for RTS and DTR (MCR Registers for Serial COM port) and get() routine for DCD, RI, DSR, CTS (MSR Registers for Serial COM port).

Can we set and reset the Pins of DCD, RI, DSR and CTS by writing into these registers as done for RTS and DTR?

Also, can we get the status of RTS and DTR as in MSR?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to answer your question.  This is a website dealing with programming issues, so please tell us what programming language and development platform you are using.  If this is strictly a question about manipulating the pins on a UART, you need to ask it over at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am using C in Windows for this (using bios.h etc).

Comment: Depending on which version of Windows you are running, you might not even be allowed to do this.  Microsoft prefers that you interface with the machine at a higher level, using device drivers or the Win32 API.  See http://www.robbayer.com/files/serial-win.pdf for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Those signals are *input* signals.  The device controls them, not you.

Not a problem for DTR and RTS, they are *output* signals.